# R: system() cannot use bash function defined in .bashrc

Tags: python, r, bash, configuration, path

**Question**

My default Python is 2.7, but I have a script that requires Python 3.4. I am trying to create a function in R that will:

1. Switch to Python 3.4
2. Run this script
3. Switch back to Python 2.7
4. Import results into R

To switch between Python versions, I use my cluster's "dotkit" system, like this:

```
use Python-2.7
use Python-3.4
```

"use" is a bash function that is imported in my .bashrc file. It sets all of my path variables (PATH, LIBRARY_PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, CPATH, C_INCLUDE_PATH, etc). The problem is that when I try to call this function in R, I get the following error:

```
system('use Python-3.4')
sh: use: command not found
```

It seems like this is a problem with my PATH. I am using the correct shell:

```
system('echo $SHELL')
/bin/bash
```

My $PATH variable also looks good. However, when I create a script that essentially does the same thing:

load_py34.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
use Python-3.4
```

and call this script through R, then it actually runs, but for some reason, it doesn't change my python version within R. (I have verified that this script works from the command line.)

```
> R
> system('python --version')
Python 2.7.1
> system('sh load_py34.sh')
Prepending: R-3.4 (ok)
> system('python --version')
Python 2.7.1
```

So I'm a little confused, but if anyone can help, I would really appreciate it.

---

**Suggested fixes**

When I combine them into a single command, I still have the same problem:

```
> system("sh load_py34.sh; python --version")
Prepending: Python-3.4 (already loaded)
Python 2.7.1
```

When I try calling bash directly, I still have a problem with the PATH:

```
> system("bash -c 'use Python-3.4; python --version'")
bash: use: command not found
Python 2.7.1
```

Comment: When I combine them in a single call, I get the same error. I will update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

`.bashrc` is only loaded for interactive bash sessions.

> "use" is a bash function that is imported in my `.bashrc` file. It sets
> all of my path variables.

If set via `export`, the environment of the calling process will not be altered.

> export [-fn] [name[=word]] ... The supplied names are marked for automatic export to the environment of subsequently executed commands. (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)

Child processes do not normally have access to the parent process' environment. (This poses a problem because `system()` creates a sub-process.)

The `source` and `.` built-ins execute the commands in the current shell environment, hence why your script works.

Other commands (executables, non-shell-builtins) are executed by the *fork-and-exec* mechanism, whereby the executing shell process forks, creating a child process with an identical environment and state. This new child process is the process in which the command is executed. Changes to the environment of that process are not replicated to the parent's environment.

This means that you will not be able to rely on `system('...')` to modify the environment of the R process, or that of processes spawned by subsequent `system()` invocations.

In a single invocation to `system()`, you can construct a command-line that changes the environment of the spawned shell like so:

```
bash -c 'source ~/.bashrc; use Python-3.4; python --version'
```

Mind you, `~/.bashrc` is not really the best place to put this functionality (might be subjective).

Answer (score 0):

When you call `system()` it uses `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`. `sh` doesn't read your `.bashrc` file when it starts up, so it does not know any of the functions you've defined there.

To use the function from your `.bashrc`, you must get `bash` to run it instead:

```
system("bash -c 'use Python-3.4; python --version'")
```

*Edit: placement of closing single quote.*

Comment: This gives me the same error (see updated question).